# why android null pointer exception error occur?

Tags: android

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.widget.Filter com.example.olx_app.AdapterAd.getFilter()' on a null object reference
at com.example.olx_app.HomeFragment$1.onTextChanged(HomeFragment.java:113)

HomeFragment.java

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

```
private FragmentHomeBinding binding;

private static final String TAG="HOME_TAG";

private static final int MAX_DISTANCE_TO_LOAD_ADS_KM =10;

//Context for this fragment class
private Context mContext;

//adArrayList to hold ads list to show in RecycleView
private ArrayList<ModelAd> adArrayList;

//AdapterAd class instance to set to RecycleView to show Ads list
private AdapterAd adapterAd;

//show nearby location
private SharedPreferences locationSp;

private double currentLatitude =0.0;
private double currentLongitude = 0.0;
private String currentAddress ="";

@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    super.onAttach(context);
}

public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(mContext),container,false);
    return binding.getRoot();
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


    //init the shared Preferences p1. name of SharedPreferences file , p2. mode of SharedPreferences
    locationSp = mContext.getSharedPreferences("LOCATION_SP", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //get saved current Latitude , Longitude ,address from SharedPreferences .
    //In next we will pick these info from map and save in it
    currentLatitude = locationSp.getFloat("CURRENT_LATITUDE",0.0f);
    currentLongitude = locationSp.getFloat("CURRENT_LONGITUDE",0.0f);
    currentAddress = locationSp.getString("CURRENT_ADDRESS","");

    //if current location is not 0
    if(currentLatitude !=0.0 && currentLongitude !=0.0)
    {
        binding.locationTv.setText(currentAddress);
    }

    //call , load categories
    loadCategories();
    //call , load all ads
    loadAds("All");

    binding.searchEt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onTextChanged: Query: "+s);

            try {
               String query = s.toString();
                    adapterAd.getFilter().filter(query);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "onTextChanged: ",e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    binding.locationCv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,LocationPickerActivity.class);
            locationPickerActivityResult.launch(intent);
        }
    });

}


private final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> locationPickerActivityResult = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                //check if from map , location is picked or not
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: RESULT_OK");
                    Intent data = result.getData();

                    if (data != null) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: Location picked");
                        //get location info from intent
                        currentLatitude = data.getDoubleExtra("latitude", 0.0);
                        currentLongitude = data.getDoubleExtra("longitude", 0.0);
                        currentAddress = data.getStringExtra("address");
                        //save location info to shared preferences to when we launch app next time we don't need to pick again
                        locationSp.edit()
                                .putFloat("CURRENT_LATITUDE", Float.parseFloat("" + currentLatitude))
                                .putFloat("CURRENT_LONGITUDE", Float.parseFloat("" + currentLongitude))
                                .putString("CURRENT_ADDRESS", currentAddress)
                                .apply();
                        //set the picked address
                        binding.locationTv.setText(currentAddress);
                        //after picking address reload all ads again based on newly picked location
                        loadAds("All");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: Cancelled!");
                    Utils.toast(mContext, "Cancelled!");
                }
            }
        }
);

private void loadCategories()
{
    //init categoryArrayList
    ArrayList<ModelCategory> categoryArrayList =  new ArrayList<>();
    //ModelCategory instance to show all products
    ModelCategory modelCategoryAll = new ModelCategory("All" , R.drawable.all);
    categoryArrayList.add(modelCategoryAll);

    //get categories from utils class and add in categoryArrayList
    for(int i=0; i <Utils.categories.length ;i++)
    {
        //hold category from current index
        ModelCategory modelCategory = new ModelCategory(Utils.categories[i], Utils.categoryIcons[i]);
        //add modelCategory to categoryArrayList
        categoryArrayList.add(modelCategory);
    }

    //setup AdapterCategory
    AdapterCategory adapterCategory = new AdapterCategory(mContext, categoryArrayList, new RvListenerCategory() {
        @Override
        public void onCategoryClick(ModelCategory modelCategory) {
            loadAds(modelCategory.getCategory());
        }
    });

    //set adapter to the RecycleView like categoriesRv
    binding.categoriesRv.setAdapter(adapterCategory);
}
```

private void loadAds(String category) {
Log.d(TAG, "loadAds: Category: "+category);

```
    /*//init adArrayList before starting adding data into it
    adArrayList = new ArrayList<>();*/

    //Firebase DB listener to load ads based on category & distance
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Ads");
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            //clear adArrayList each time starting adding data into it
            adArrayList.clear();


            //load ads list
            for(DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                //prepare modelAd with all data from Firebase DB
                ModelAd modelAd = ds.getValue(ModelAd.class);
                //function call with returned value as distance in km
                assert modelAd != null;
                double distance = calculateDistanceKm(modelAd.getLatitude(), modelAd.getLongitude());
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: distance: " + distance);
                //filter
                if (category.equals("All")) {
                    //category All is selected , now check distance if is <= required e.x. 10km then show
                    if (distance <= MAX_DISTANCE_TO_LOAD_ADS_KM) {
                        //distance is <= required e.x. 10km Add to list
                        adArrayList.add(modelAd);
                    }
                } else {
                    //some category is selected e.x. mobile
                    if (modelAd.getCategory().equals(category)) {
                        if (distance <= MAX_DISTANCE_TO_LOAD_ADS_KM) {
                            //distance is <= required e.x. 10km Add to list
                            adArrayList.add(modelAd);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

           adapterAd = new AdapterAd(mContext,adArrayList);
            binding.adsRv.setAdapter(adapterAd);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}

private double calculateDistanceKm(double adLatitude, double adLongitude)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "calculateDistanceKm: currentLatitude: "+ currentLatitude);
    Log.d(TAG, "calculateDistanceKm: currentLongitude: "+currentLongitude);
    Log.d(TAG, "calculateDistanceKm: adLatitude: "+adLatitude);
    Log.d(TAG, "calculateDistanceKm: adLongitude: "+adLongitude);

    //source Location i.e. user's current location
    Location startPoint = new Location(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    startPoint.setLatitude(currentLatitude);
    startPoint.setLongitude(currentLongitude);

    //Destination Location i.e. Ad's Location
    Location endPoint = new Location(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    endPoint.setLatitude(adLatitude);
    endPoint.setLongitude(adLongitude);

    //calculate distance
    double distanceInMeters = startPoint.distanceTo(endPoint);
    double distanceInKm = distanceInMeters / 1000 ;

    return distanceInKm;
}
```

}

AdapterAd.java

public class AdapterAd extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterAd.HolderAd> implements Filterable
{
private RowAdBinding binding;

```
private static final String TAG = "ADAPTER_AD_TAG";

private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

private Context context;

//adArrayList the list of the Ads
public ArrayList<ModelAd> adArrayList;

private ArrayList<ModelAd> filterList;

private FilterAd filter;

public AdapterAd(Context context, ArrayList<ModelAd> adArrayList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.adArrayList = adArrayList;
    this.filterList = adArrayList;

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public HolderAd onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //inflate the row_ad.xml
    binding = RowAdBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context),parent,false);
    return new HolderAd(binding.getRoot());
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HolderAd holder, int position) {
    //get data from particular position of list and set to UI
    ModelAd modelAd = adArrayList.get(position);

    String title = modelAd.getTitle();
    String description = modelAd.getDescription();
    String address = modelAd.getAddress();
    String price = modelAd.getPrice();
    String condition = modelAd.getCondition();

    //function call : load first image from available images of Ad
    loadAdFirstImage(modelAd,holder);

    //set data to UI views of row_ad.xml
    holder.titleTv.setText(title);
    holder.descriptionTv.setText(description);
    holder.addressTv.setText(address);
    holder.priceTv.setText(price);
    holder.conditionTv.setText(condition);

}

private void loadAdFirstImage(ModelAd modelAd, HolderAd holder) {
    Log.d(TAG, "loadAdFirstImage: ");
    //load first image from available images of Ad

    //adId to get image of it
    String adId = modelAd.getId();
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Ads");
    reference.child(adId).child("Images").limitToFirst(1)
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot)
                {
                    //it return 1 image as we have used query .limitToFirst(1)
                    for(DataSnapshot ds:snapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                        //get Url of image
                        String imageUrl =""+ds.child("imageUrl").getValue();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: imageUrl: "+imageUrl);
                        //set image to Image view
                        try
                        {
                            Glide.with(context)
                                    .load(imageUrl)
                                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_image_gray)
                                    .into(holder.imageIv);
                        }catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange: ",e );
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return adArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    //init the filter obj only if it is null
    if(filter == null)
    {
        filter = new FilterAd(this,adArrayList);
    }
    return filter;
}


class HolderAd extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    //UI views of the row_ad.xml
    ShapeableImageView imageIv;
    TextView titleTv, descriptionTv , addressTv , conditionTv , priceTv;
    ImageButton favBtn;

    public HolderAd(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        //init UI views of the row_ad.xml
        imageIv = binding.imageIv;
        titleTv = binding.titleTv;
        descriptionTv = binding.descriptionTv;
        favBtn = binding.favBtn;
        addressTv = binding.addressTv;
         conditionTv = binding.conditionTv;
        priceTv = binding.priceTv;
    }
}
```

}

FilterAd.java

public class FilterAd extends Filter
{
public AdapterAd adapter;

```
public ArrayList<ModelAd> filterList;

public FilterAd(AdapterAd adapter, ArrayList<ModelAd> filterList) {
    this.adapter = adapter;
    this.filterList = filterList;
}

@Override
protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
    //perform filter based on what user type

    FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

    if(constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0)
    {
        //search query is not null and not empty , we can perform filter
        //convert query to upper case to make search not case sensitive
        constraint = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();

        //hold the filtered list of ads based on user searched query
        ArrayList<ModelAd> filteredModels = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i<filterList.size(); i++)
        {
            //Ad filter based on Brand,Category,Condition,Title . if any of these matches add it to the filterModels list
            if(filterList.get(i).getBrand().toUpperCase().contains(constraint) ||
                    filterList.get(i).getCategory().toUpperCase().contains(constraint) ||
                    filterList.get(i).getCondition().toUpperCase().contains(constraint) ||
                    filterList.get(i).getTitle().toUpperCase().contains(constraint)) {
                //Filter matched add to filterModels list
                filteredModels.add(filterList.get(i));
            }
        }
        results.count = filteredModels.size();
        results.values = filteredModels;
    }
    else
    {
        //the search query is either null or empty . we can't perform filter . return full list
        results.count = filterList.size();
        results.values = filterList;
    }
    return results;
}

@SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
    //publish the filtered result

    adapter.adArrayList = (ArrayList<ModelAd>) results.values;
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

// Declare the AdapterAd reference globally in your HomeFragment class
private AdapterAd adapter;

// ...

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

```
// Initialize the adapter here
adapter = new AdapterAd(mContext, adArrayList);
binding.adsRv.setAdapter(adapter);

// ... Your other code ...

binding.searchEt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onTextChanged: Query: " + s);

        try {
            query = s.toString();
            // Now you can safely call getFilter() on the initialized adapter
            adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onTextChanged: ", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
});
```

}

private void loadAds(String category) {

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        // ...
        adArrayList.clear();
        // ...
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Notify the adapter that the data has changed
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    }
});
```

}

I can try this but not solved problem

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are accessing `adapterAd`, but it may not have been initialized, as you are initializing it in your success callback of Firebase database.

Approach 1 : Do a `null` check before accessing your adapter

```
try {
    String query = s.toString();
    if(adapterAd != null){
        adapterAd.getFilter().filter(query);
    }
}
```

Approach 2: Initialize your adapter with empty list and then update the adapter after you get data from Firebase.

```
// initialize the adapter in your onCreateView()
adArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
adapterAd = new AdapterAd(mContext,adArrayList);
binding.adsRv.setAdapter(adapterAd);

// notify that adapter that list is changed in your success callback

ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            //clear adArrayList each time starting adding data into it
            adArrayList.clear();


            //load ads list
            for(DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            // your code
            }
           // use this to update your adapter
           adapterAd.notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
```